# Font showing strange characters in konsole (Kubuntu 20.04)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts

I've just installed Kubuntu 20.04 and I get strange characters in my Konsole. I've tried with a couple of fonts and the problem remains the same. Here is a screen capture:
[image]

Look at the column after the "4096". Does someone have an idea how to fix that? The same problem occurs in Kate's console, actually.

Note that I was previously on 16.04 and 12.04, and I never experienced this problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ stole your month!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you ran `ls -l` to show that image, looks like the Month for the modified date is not showing correctly.  Some things to try:

- Check that Language and region system settings is correct and the language settings.
- Run `echo $LANG` to see what the console language is and that it matches the system setting, and that the language is currently installed on the system. You may need to find out what packages you need and install them `sudo apt install {language packages}`
- Check that your font setting is correct and supports your chosen language
- You mentioned you already tried a few fonts.  I use Hack font or FiraCode which supports a lot of different symbols, you could try those if
- For some commands you can enter `LANG={language-code} {command}` to force it in a particular language (The language should be installed on your system first). For example: `LANG=fr_FR ls -l` or `LANG=en_GB ls -l`

Comment: Fixed! I removed english (US) from my system languages and replaced it by français then changed my settings to fr_CA... Now LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8 and my month are french abrev rather than those symbols... I also noticed that the month of my clock (login screen) is correctly written and was not but I did not know the problems were the same... ThX!